# I want to iterate two loops one is list and the other is a statement in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two one variable and one list, and I want to iterate them and the result should be:

```
foo = click 

bar = (element1, element2, element3)
```

**Desired output:**

```
click

element1

click

element2

click

element3
```

I have tried like:

```
for y in range(1, 3):
   
  for x in range(len(loop3)):
       
  loop1.click()
       
  loop3[x].click()
```

Comment: This  `(element1, element2, element3)` is *not* a `list`, you know that right? Please read [ask] and update your question with [mre].

Comment: + format (and indent!) your code: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
for i in bar:
    print(foo)
    print(i)
```